# Windows authentication not working properly on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, internet-explorer, iis, windows-authentication

So this is kind of odd.

My scenario:

- Web server running IIS, hosting asp.net applications
- SQL server

As they are on separate servers, I had to set up kerberos delegation. I have got this working.
So a user goes to asp.net application hosted on the web server, and it authenticates them to the SQL server.

On one of my web apps, when they go to it in Chrome, I get the error page with SQL authentication failed due to Anonymous user. If they go to the same app in IE, it works correctly.

Here is the really odd part - if they then go to it again in Chrome, it works!

So I guess there is some inconsistency in how Chrome authenticates.
I found someone suggesting it might be to do with the IIS negotiation providers, but as it needs kerberos delegation I have to have "Negotiate" as the first option or it fails completely.

I guess I could just tell users they have to use IE, but I would prefer to get it to work in Chrome.

Any thoughts?

(Possibly similar to [Kerberos not working with Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768726/kerberos-not-working-with-chrome) but it's all on intranet zone, so don't think there's anything to whitelist)

Comment: So I tested adding a value in registry as per post linked above.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"AuthNegotiateDelegateWhitelist"="*"

It solved the issue.
Annoying, as it's going to be a pain to get this pushed out to all users.

Comment: I know this is old, but the above comment might open up users to an extreme risk of credentials leak to any website the users visit. Please research before doing that.